# How to derive the spectral projection operator in finite element method?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, finite-element-method

For a compact self-adjoint operator $T$, the spectral operator can be defined as follows:
$$E(\lambda) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}(z-T)^{-1}dz$$.

For a finite dimensional approximate operator $T_h$, similarly, we have
$$E_h(\lambda) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}(z-T_h)^{-1}dz$$.

My question is then what do you mean by $E_h(\lambda)u$ for any $u\in V$, since $T_h:L^2 \rightarrow V_h$?